# Hair fall of my dog

Tags: dogs

I have Indian female dog there is lot of hairfall in the place where she sits. Any remedy for it or how can I control her hairfall?

Comment: you need to add more information to your question,is the fur loss in one area or is it all over,has your dog got bald areas if so how does the skin look,what type of dog do you have and how old is she,what type of food do you give her.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem... Does your dog have hairloss on some spot on her body or do you notice lots of fallen hair in your house where she usually sits? Please [edit] your question to add more information. If there are bald spots on your dog a picture is very helpful as well.

Comment: Also, is it [getting] summer now where you are? Right now, wherever my dog is, there will also be a lot of hairfall - but that's perfectly normal this time of the year.

Comment: you can take a look here https://www.academyanimal.com/why-is-my-pet-shedding-so-much all animals with fur shed humans shed hair too but it is not as sesonal as it is for cats and dogs.